# .NET IsValidXml Extension Method Performance

Tags: c#, .net, xml, validation, xml-validation

I have a legacy application that I inherited that passes a lot of XML around as Strings.

I often need the ability to check if a String will be valid XML. What is the fastest and least expensive way to check if a string is valid XML in .NET?

I'm working in .NET 3.5 and would most likely use this as an extension method (off of string) in this one project within the solution.

**UPDATE**:
What I mean by "valid" in my case is properly formed XML. I don't need to validate resources or schema.

Comment: What, in your case, is "valid"? Do you just mean properly formed, or are you expecting it to match a DTD/schema? Does that mean you need to be able to resolve referenced resources?

Comment: Good point. I'll modify my question.

Comment: I wonder if I should call my method IsProperXml? or IsWellFormedXml?

Comment: At that level, it sounds like `IsXml` would work (IMHO).

Comment: These terms have specific meanings:  a string is *well-formed* if it conforms to XML's syntax rules, i.e. if it's an XML document.  An XML document is *valid* if it conforms to a DTD or schema.  All valid XML documents are well-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to validate the well-formedness of an XML string without parsing it.  And a quick benchmark shows that the fastest way to parse a string to see if it's valid (actually the fastest way to parse the particular string I using as a test case)is with an XmlReader:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int iterations = 20000;
        const string xml = @"<foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo><foo><bar><baz a='b' c='d'/></bar><bar/></foo></bar><bar/></foo>";

        Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();

        st.Start();
        for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++)
        {
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
            {
                while (xr.Read())
                {
                }
            }
        }
        st.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("XmlReader: {0} ms.", st.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        st.Reset();
        st.Start();
        for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++)
        {
            XElement.Parse(xml);
        }
        st.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("XElement: {0} ms.", st.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        st.Reset();
        st.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            XmlDocument d= new XmlDocument();
            d.LoadXml(xml);
        }
        st.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("XmlDocument: {0} ms.", st.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        st.Reset();
        st.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                XPathDocument d = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));                    
            }
        }
        st.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("XPathDocument: {0} ms.", st.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

On my machine `XmlReader` is nearly twice as fast as any of the alternatives.  This makes sense.  Though I haven't used Reflector to check, I'd be very surprised if `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`, and `XPathDocument` weren't all using `XmlReader` under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a built-in facility in .NET to validate the formed-ness (?) of XML without parsing it. Given that, something like this should work:

```
public static class XmlUtilities
{
    public static bool IsXml(this string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) return false;

        try
        {
            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            doc.LoadXml(data);

            return true;            
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Steven, Please don't edit answers in a way that fundamentally alters the way in which they work. Catching all exceptions was intentional and is appropriate. Though it *could* be more specific and catch only `XmlException`, changing it to use `DebuggerStepThrough` is not at all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Adam, and the XElement version :

```
public static class XmlUtilities
{

    public static bool IsXml(this string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) return false;

        try
        {
            var doc = XElement.Parse(data)

            return true;            
        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would someone edit an answer to a question that has been answered already, by changing the meaning of the code...
posting a comment could be more friendly, in my opinion!